# How to fix Visual Studio not creating a Proxy class when adding a WSDL Web Reference after upgrading DevExpress to 21.2?

Tags: web-reference

i am fighting with this since more than a day and did not find a solution. Yesterday DevExpress requested upgrade references from 20.x to 21.2, so i confirmed the wizard. It somehow cleaned all references, including a very important one to a WSDL service. Already this was strange - i work with this project on this computer since several months and no update was offered.

This already happened in the past, and was quickly solved by re-adding a web reference (that one in Advanced options of adding a service). But this time the service is found, i click Add reference and VS does not create the Proxy class. It is displayed in the Web references, but can't be referenced.
When i try the other way (Service reference without the Advanced option), the proxy is created, application starts normally but when calling Login method of that WS, i get an error, that some method is not known (http://localhost/LoginRequest). I think that there is some problem with namespaces. But i'd prefer to make the old webreference working. I have tried to change the namespace to the real machine name, to that text which is in wsdl but still nothing.

I use it in several other projects and it is working well there. WSDL has not been changed since years, the supplier ensures me that they have not touched this since many years and did no updates on the server.

Any idea how to solve this? And why does it happen, when it worked in the past? VS update?

Thanks!
Best regards
Honza

Comment: Sorry for any incorrectly translated Visual Studio texts (webreference etc.). VS was automatically installed in czech version (i think because my Windows is CS) and since, i am terribly confused. Following any instruction when the texts differ and translation often is not 100% correct, or reporting an error displayed in CS, is a nightmare.